# How to go from 11.04 to 10.04

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, screen, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to roll back Ubuntu to a previous version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version)

Ok, so I was running fine on 10.04 then I thought "why not upgrade to 11.04"

So I did and a some bad stuff happened. Once I boot or try install the screen goes very faint were you cannot read the screen so I cant install, and when I do install I can use the OS because I cant see what I'm doing.

So how can I go back to 10.04? Will I just download the ISO and burn it to a disc then use that or will I need to format first? and if so, how?

Sorry for being a no0b but I'm without a pc and I need it for coursework. (I'm using the Live CD with "try Ubuntu without installing").