# Degrade from Ubuntu 11.04 to 10.04

Tags: 11.04, 10.04, hardware, acer, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to go from 11.04 to 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39430/how-to-go-from-11-04-to-10-04)

I want to degrade my ubuntu from 11.04 to 10.04. After upgrading I am facing series of problems :( . Its sometime logged out automatically. Its freeze sometime. I don't want to debug the things any more. Now a days I spend most of the times for debugging OS problems. In my ubuntu 10.04 I am not face any bigger problems.

Is there any way to degrade to 10.04 or 10.10...?

FYI my hardware configuration is

I am using Acer 5740.
[image: my system configuration]